# Pandas Dataframe UnicodeDecodeError with Twitter Data

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, pandas

I have a MongoDB filled with data from the twitter streaming API (Tweet,Time,Geo-Location) and am trying to create a dataframe in Pandas using the data. I have tried exporting to csv, json, and connecting directly to the database using PyMongo to create the Dataframe and am still getting the same error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1194:ordinal not in range(128)
```

When importing from the csv I tried using the encoding='utf-8' argument but still got the same error. I am not very familiar with text encoding so any help would be appreciated.

Heres an example of a record that throws the error:

```
                Text                                    Time                 Geo
I'm downÃ°Å¸Ëœâ€š https://t.co/ZPzy0GOF5T      2015-04-13T15:56:27.000Z
```

And then the code:

```
df  = pd.read_csv('test1.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

And the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 89: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems to be an encoding issue when I exported the collection from mongo to csv, it turned emojis into these strange characters.

Comment: Have you tried `encoding='utf-16'`?

Comment: I tried `encoding='utf-16',engine='python` and got: `UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM`

Comment: Well you'll have to provide data and code so that others can help

Comment: Edited with example.

Comment: I'd look at seeing if you can export it in it's raw form, otherwise this must be a common problem and someone somewhere has probably coded a method to strip the emojis out of the text